# Setting pointer to NULL fixes project

Tags: c++, pointers, null, exc-bad-access

On a semi-large project (~5000+ lines of code)...

I have a class with a pointer as one of its fields. The pointer was declared but not initialized:

```cpp
Apple *apple;
```

In the class's constructor, I initialized the pointer if it was `NULL`:

```cpp
if (apple == NULL) {
    apple = new Apple();
}
```

Further down in the project's code, I did:

```cpp
apple->color = "red";
```

The program worked fine for **months**, until today it gave me a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error, because the `apple` pointer was not explicitly initialized to `NULL` and started out with some garbage value - so the `NULL` check failed, and dereferencing it gave a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

So my question is - how did the program work fine for **months**? Was the pointer set to `NULL` previously by pure luck?

*Note:* I made no changes to the code here, only changes elsewhere in the project that didn't touch this/seem irrelevant.

Comment: If `apple` is a member variable in a class, then it will have an *indeterminate* value when objects of the class is constructed, unless explicitly initialized (either inline or through a constructor initializer list). Please try to create a [mre] to show us, as that will help us understand your problem much better, and then also be able to help you much better.

Comment: *"I made no changes to the code here"* -- That's one piece. Were there any changes to the build options? To the compiler? To anything in the build environment? You entered the land of implementation-defined behavior, so any change to the implementation can change the behavior.

Comment: *So my question is - how did the program work fine for months?* -- Welcome to the world of C++ and undefined behavior.  *I made no changes to the code here, only changes elsewhere in the project that didn't touch this/seem irrelevant.* -- You changed the binary executable in some way, and thus you exposed the bug.  Also emphasizing **months** means nothing -- C++ programs have been known to work for years with hidden bugs, only to be discovered by "irrelevant code changes" or changes in the build settings / compiler.

Comment: In addition, seasoned C++ programmers would just discover this as an obvious bug, and won't even question why the program "worked before".

Comment: You were very unlucky for months.  Finally your bad luck ran out, and the program crashed with some very helpful diagnostic information.  That's the nature of **undefined behavior**.

Comment: I once worked at a job where the code was basically riddled with undefined behavior, but the maintainers were so afraid of touching the code since the code "worked for years", thus changes were not made.  I left that place pretty quickly after that.

Comment: A side note: 5,000 lines is not really a semi-large project...

Comment: I'd recommend testing with the address sanitizer built into your compiler. It's pretty good at detecting memory errors.

Comment: @Eljay it seems odd to describe a working program as "unlucky", but you're absolutely right.  The worst possible outcome of undefined behavior is to work, because it prevents you from discovering the bug.

Comment: My project has 56,462,452 lines, thanks to the power of `wc`.  I think it qualifies as large.  It has mammoth and nigh incomprehensible functions that have over 5,000 lines.  (I didn't write any of those.)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie _You changed the binary executable in some way, and thus you exposed the bug_. This is what I was thinking, thanks for confirming this. Also, to be specific, the _obvious bug_ is that the pointer was uninitialized, correct?

Comment: @VladFeinstein I guess the term "large" is relative.. it's large compared to a simple coding exercise.. but yes tiny in comparison to a company 1,000,000+ lines project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell decisively, but probably yes, the program worked by sheer luck.

If you don't explicitly initialize a pointer you can't assume anything about it, and TBH, it's not surprising that the program started crashing, but that it worked up until now.

Answer (score 1):

1. In a constructor, you don't need to check for "previous" state of the variables, just set it to what you need, unconditionally.
2. Are you sure you want a pointer to `Apple` and not that object itself? If you had in your class

   Apple apple;

it would be default-constructed for you, and you won't need to explicitly `delete` it (that you may forget, leaking memory).